# Displaying a resized image in a web page causes black-on white color inversion

Tags: html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Consider the following page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img height="80" src='https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/static/images/badges/en_badge_web_generic.png'/>
        <img src='https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/static/images/badges/en_badge_web_generic.png'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

When visualizing this page using the following setup:

- Windows 11
- dark or light theme active (doesn't matter)
- Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge

notice how the resized image undergoes a color inversion: black becomes white, and white becomes black. When the image is displayed in its native size, color inversion does not happen.

Under Firefox, no color inversion is taking place.

I tried to find where this behavior is documented in the HTML spec, but couldn't find anything.

Is this a well-known behavior, documented in some (possibly other) spec?

EDIT: screen capture added as requested

[image: Chrome/Edge resized image issue]

Comment: That seems like a bug. Does the problem show up in a screenshot, and if so, can you add a screenshot here?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see this in Chrome 114.0.5735.198 using your HTML.  What's your graphics card?  It's strange that it inverted black and white, but not the colors.

Comment: I'm using the same version. And BTW, I have no extension installed. My gfx card is a GTX 1080, drivers 528.02

Comment: If I set the height to 200 instead of 80, the colors are not inverted! Also, I observe the same behavior with CSS (background-image and background-size)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. This behavior is caused by the `force dark` setting that is enabled on my computers for both Chrome and Edge. It was defined as `Enabled` (not `Default`) here:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark
```

This setting forces colors to be dark, but for some reason it creates this behavior with images. Not sure what to think of this.